# Can we display ads in android widget

Tags: android

I am creating a free version of android widget, and i want to display ads in it. But when we add Google Adsense in xml like

```
   <com.google.ads.GoogleAdView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

it shows following error. (I added the jar files also)

```
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.GoogleAdView
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:930)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:219)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:250)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:73)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.GoogleAdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
09-04 11:14:00.418: W/AppWidgetHostView(2561):  ... 15 more
```

Anybody suggest that is it possible to display ads in android widget in anyother ways. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to get data via a web service and display it in your widget.

Comment: So, we cannot use Google Adsense to show ads in widget right?

Comment: I think this will help you. https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/android/

Comment: yes, thanks, but already i saw that document. my doubt is, Is it possible to use Google adsense in android widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Widgets use `RemoteViews` to display their screen. `RemoteViews` typically require that all the display classes be available WITHOUT your entire APK having been loaded. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout shows you what View classes you can use: you currently can not use any custom views, therefore there is no way right now to use a `com.google.ads.GoogleAdView` in a widget.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could show [Custom Native Ads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native#loading_custom_native_ad_formats) in your widget. Instead of [Banner Ads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner#app_events) or [Interstitial ads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/interstitial) they not force you to use any specific type of view.

However, keep in mind that in such case you will face with 2 other problems:

1. Your app is responsible now for display the ads content, handling clicks and notify sdk about them.
2. Widget specific problem. You should keep in mind that your content data objects could be destroyed when your app is killed by the system. But ad content on widget is still will be shown. This may lead to app misbehavior because.

*So, in resolution:*

I agree that now it looks like we can't use common ads in widgets. However, if you need just show some images or text, that not require user interaction or reporting clicks to sdk - you could try to use Custom Native Ads and integrate that content in your widgets.